# Change table fields to display only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following code which is working OK. When I click, it creates a new row for the table.
All the rows are editable, I want just the row which is added (when clicking on the button) to be editable and the rest to be `display only` .i.e.

> 1. All the table rows should be `display only`.
> 2. When you click on 'Add Row' button it adds a new row. I wish to add a **V** button to the newly created row that will save its data in the table and set it to `display only`.

thanks

Btw this is MVC5 application which run bootstrap

```
<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        // initialize the table
        initRowEvents(jQuery(document));
    });

    function initRowEvents(scope) {
        scope.find('.data-cell').attr('title', 'Click to edit').on('keypress keyup change', function () {

        }).end().find('.delete-button').click(function () {
            // remove the row
            $(this).parents('.data-row').remove();

        });
    }

    function addRow() {
        jQuery('<div class="data-row"><input class="data-cell data-category" /><input class="data-cell data-value" type="number" step="10" /><input class="data-button delete-button" type="button" value="X" /></div>').prependTo('#data-table').each(function () {
            initRowEvents(jQuery(this));
        });
    }

</script>


<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow()" class="data-button" id="add-row" />
<br />
<div id="data-table">
    <div class="data-row">
        <input class="data-cell data-category" value="aaa" />
        <input class="data-cell data-value" value="4000" type="number" step="10" />
        <input class="data-button delete-button" type="button" value="X" />
    </div>
    <div class="data-row">
        <input class="data-cell data-category" value="frc" />
        <input class="data-cell data-value" value="1882" type="number" step="10" />
        <input class="data-button delete-button" type="button" value="X" />
    </div>


</div>
<br />
```

Comment: Could you explain the 2nd point a little more detailed? I get that the rows loaded by default should be display only, so does it have to be on input box or should be just text? And then the new rows should have the 'V' mark button, do you mean the downward caret? And what is this button supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a **[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/GHw9q/2/)**

```
$('input').attr('readonly','readonly');
```

I assume by 'display only' you mean 'not editable/readonly'.

Second I added a new button for add.

```
<input class="data-button addnew-button" type="button" value="V" />
```

Comment: Just one last question ,there is a way that when you click on add row it will check if already there is a new row for edit if not create new row otherwise dont.thanks in advance!